# Is it sub-optimal to use HAProxy as a load balancer for RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy

I'm in the process of figuring out the optimum topology for my RabbitMQ cluster. I want highly available queues. I have seen a lot of posts about using HAProxy as a round-robin load-balancer in front of the RMQ nodes.

My understanding is that in an RMQ cluster with a mirrored queue, a message will first be routed to the master node for that queue, then that message is replicated to the mirrors. RMQ clients can be configured with multiple nodes, and the client is aware of which node is the master for its queue, so will always route the messages there.

But using HAProxy, I lose client-cluster-awareness.

E.g. I have a 3 node cluster with a queue with 3 mirrors. Node 1 is the master, 2 and 3 are slaves.

- My producer produces a message and it hits HAProxy. HAProxy routes that message to node1. node1 is the master so it writes to its queue and then propagates the message to nodes 2 and 3.
- The next message hits HAProxy and gets routed to node2. Node2 then has to forward this request back to node1 before it is written and propagated.
- The next message gets routed to node3, and again, has to be sent back to node1.

So only 1 in 3 messages are not having to be re-routed. Plus nodes 2 and 3 are doing unnecessary work receiving messages and routing them to node1.

There is, of course, the advantage of only having to configure one endpoint on clients, and being able to change cluster topology freely, but am I correct in saying that this is not an optimal setup in terms of message throughput?

Comment: If you have a three node cluster there's really not much need to mirror to all three nodes. You can answer your own question by running benchmarks. I suggest using PerfTest.

Answer (score 0):

In a common scenario, no.

You thought about the message routing but forgot the connection handling. One can't have all of its connections to only one node, besides that, a loadbalancer will help to shut down one node at a time for maintenance.